# How would I center align the following buttons using CSS

Tags: html, css

How would I center align the following buttons on my webapp using CSS?

```
  <a href="#carbcounter" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">The Carb Counter</a>
  <a href="#add&delete" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Add & Delete Produce</a>`
  `<a href="#Login" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all" data-icon="action">Log in to the Blog</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to do the links in the center:

```css
.btn-outer{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.btn-outer a{
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-outer">
  <a href="#carbcounter" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">The Carb Counter</a>
  <a href="#add&delete" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Add & Delete Produce</a> 
  <a href="#Login" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all" data-icon="action">Log in to the Blog</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfect that worked - Thank you very much! And if i wanted to vertically align them with a slight gap between each btn how would i do that?

Comment: I have edited the code and I have added "flex-direction: column;" in outer div and added margin in button. I think this can help you.

Comment: if my answer is correct can you please upvote the answer.